# Passar e retornar vetor de tipo definido por struct como parâmetro de uma função em C

Tags: c, array, struct, funções

Estou encontrando erros para o seguinte código:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

const int limite = 100;

//Definição da estrutura Conjunto como um tipo de variável Conjunto
typedef struct Conjunto {
   int valor;
   short preenchido; //Flag para identificar se o valor do struct foi preenchido
} Conjunto;

/**
Esta função faz a leitura dinâmica de um conjunto de até 100 números inteiros.
*/
Conjunto[] lerConjunto(Conjunto[] cj) {
    char resposta;
    int i;

    //Limpar o vetor de eventual lixo de memória
    for(i = 0; i < limite; i++) {
        cj[i].valor = 0;
        cj[i].preenchido = 0;
    }

    i = 0;

    //Iniciar processo de leitura de valores
    do {
        printf("Insira o %d° valor do conjunto",i);
        scanf("%d", &cj[i].valor);  //Lê o valor
        cj[i].preenchido = true;    //Indica que naquela posição do vetor houve um valor lido

        printf("\n\nDeseja Continuar? Sim, ou Não?");
        scanf("%c", &resposta);

        system("cls"); //Limpa a tela
    } while((resposta == 's' || resposta == 'S') && i < limite);

    return cj; //Retorna o conjunto lido
}

int main() {
    //Definição de linguagem para aparecer na tela (Acentos e afins)
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    //Vetor de Struct Conjunto
    Conjunto cj1[100];
    cj1 = lerConjunto(cj1);

    Conjunto cj2[100];
    cj2 = lerConjunto(cj2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Os erros lançados são:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é como manipular o *array*.

Há um erro de sintaxe no parâmetro. Não é o tipo que deve declarar que ele é um *array* mas sim a variável deve indicar isto. É meio esquisito mas é assim.

Uma função não pode retornar um *array*, você poderia retornar um ponteiro mas teria dificuldade de jogá-lo no *array* novamente. Mas pense bem, quando você passa um *array* como parâmetro, no fundo está passando um ponteiro, ou seja, está passado o *array* por referência, então qualquer alteração feita nele, já estará presente no *array* que você passou já que a alteração é feita no endereço de memória de onde ele foi criado, não há cópia do *array* para a função chamada. Então não precisa retornar nada.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

const int limite = 100;

//Definição da estrutura Conjunto como um tipo de variável Conjunto
typedef struct Conjunto {
   int valor;
   short preenchido; //Flag para identificar se o valor do struct foi preenchido
} Conjunto;

/**
Esta função faz a leitura dinâmica de um conjunto de até 100 números inteiros.
*/
void lerConjunto(Conjunto cj[]) {
    char resposta;
    int i;

    //Limpar o vetor de eventual lixo de memória
    for(i = 0; i < limite; i++) {
        cj[i].valor = 0;
        cj[i].preenchido = 0;
    }

    i = 0;

    //Iniciar processo de leitura de valores
    do {
        printf("Insira o %d° valor do conjunto",i);
        scanf("%d", &cj[i].valor);  //Lê o valor
        cj[i].preenchido = true;    //Indica que naquela posição do vetor houve um valor lido

        printf("\n\nDeseja Continuar? Sim, ou Não?");
        scanf("%c", &resposta);

        system("cls"); //Limpa a tela
    } while((resposta == 's' || resposta == 'S') && i < limite);

}

int main() {
    //Definição de linguagem para aparecer na tela (Acentos e afins)
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    //Vetor de Struct Conjunto
    Conjunto cj1[100];
    lerConjunto(cj1);

    Conjunto cj2[100];
    lerConjunto(cj2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/THq6H8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/epdfzdnh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ArrayParameter.c).

Comment: Me ajudou bastante cara! Obrigado.